# gsub a list of words in a paragraph

Tags: regex, r

Given the following code:

```
list = c("the", "at", "ok")
paragraph = "the cat ath the hat is ok"
```

How can i remove all the words in list from 'paragraph'?

I tried doing:

`gsub(list, '', paragraph)`

but only the first item of list was removed. i know this shouldn't be complicated but this is still confuses me. Also I would like to avoid using for loops, but the apply family should be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern `"(the|at|ok)"` would match occurrences of any of the strings in your list.

It sounds, though, like you want to match those actual words but not words of which they are a part (i.e. match "the" but not "then", "at" but not "rattle", etc.)  If that's the case, you can instead use the pattern `"\\b(the|at|ok)\\b"` (where `"\\b"` is the pattern that matches at word boundaries).

You can use `paste0()` to construct the needed pattern from an arbitrary vector of matching words:

```
list <- c("the", "at", "ok")
paragraph <- "the cat ath the hat is ok"

## Construct the regular expression
pat <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(list, collapse="|"), ")\\b")    
pat
# [1] "\\b(the|at|ok)\\b"

## Use it
gsub(pat, "", paragraph)
# [1] " cat ath  hat is "
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. is there a more natural way of doing this?

Comment: @user1103294 I guess we'll find out! On a related note, I'd be interested to know whether this is faster, slower, or the same speed as processing the words one at a time in a `for` loop. In any case, this does *work*, so it's at least got *that* going for it ;)

Comment: @user1103294  josh's response is pretty natural.  you probably wouldn't use apply unless `paragraph` contains multiple strings.  btw don't call your variables `list`  ;)

Comment: @anthonydamico i think using some kind of loop explicitly is a more natural way. that's partly why i think his answer is clever, he doesn't.

Comment: @user1103294 you did say, "plz don't use `for` loops"  :)

Comment: @anthonydamico for-loop isn't the only loop in r